# Benchmark Keras model using TensforFlow Benchmark

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to benchmark the performance in the inference phase of my Keras model build with the TensorFlow backend. I was thinking that the the [Tensorflow Benchmark](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/benchmark) tool was the proper way to go.

I've managed to build and run the example on Desktop with the `tensorflow_inception_graph.pb` and everything seems to work fine.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to save the Keras model as a proper `.pb`model. I'm able to get the TensorFlow Graph from the Keras model as follows:

```
import keras.backend as K
K.set_learning_phase(0)

trained_model = function_that_returns_compiled_model()
sess = K.get_session()
sess.graph # This works

# Get the input tensor name for TF Benchmark
trained_model.input
> <tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(?, 360, 480, 3) dtype=float32>

# Get the output tensor name for TF Benchmark
trained_model.output
> <tf.Tensor 'reshape_2/Reshape:0' shape=(?, 360, 480, 12) dtype=float32>
```

I've now been trying to save the model in a couple of different ways.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.session_bundle import exporter

model = trained_model
export_path = "path/to/folder"  # where to save the exported graph
export_version = 1  # version number (integer)

saver = tf.train.Saver(sharded=True)
model_exporter = exporter.Exporter(saver)
signature = exporter.classification_signature(input_tensor=model.input, scores_tensor=model.output)
model_exporter.init(sess.graph.as_graph_def(), default_graph_signature=signature)
model_exporter.export(export_path, tf.constant(export_version), sess)
```

Which produces a folder with some files I don't know what to do with.

I would now run the Benchmark tool with something like this

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/benchmark/benchmark_model \
  --graph=tensorflow/tools/benchmark/what_file.pb \
  --input_layer="input_1:0" \
  --input_layer_shape="1,360,480,3" \
  --input_layer_type="float" \
  --output_layer="reshape_2/Reshape:0"
```

But no matter which file I'm trying to use as the `what_file.pb` I'm getting a `Error during inference: Invalid argument: Session was not created with a graph before Run()!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I got this to work. Just needed to convert all variables in the tensorflow graph to constants and then save graph definition.

Here's a small example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util

K.set_learning_phase(0)
model = function_that_returns_your_keras_model()
sess = K.get_session()

output_node_name = "my_output_node" # Name of your output node

with sess as sess:
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init_op)
    graph_def = sess.graph.as_graph_def()
    output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
                                                                 sess,
                                                                 sess.graph.as_graph_def(),
                                                                 output_node_name.split(","))
    tf.train.write_graph(output_graph_def,
                         logdir="my_dir",
                         name="my_model.pb",
                         as_text=False)
```

Now just call the TensorFlow Benchmark tool with `my_model.pb` as the graph.

Answer (score 0):

You're saving the parameters of this model and not the graph definition; to save that use `tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().SerializeToString()` and then save that to a file.

That said I don't think the benchmark tool will work since it has no way to initialize the variables your model depends on.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out and get back to you later.

Comment: So you were right. It can't initialize the variables. Do you have any idea how to overcome that issue?

Comment: The benchmark tool was not designed to be used in your use-case. Write another one.

Comment: Hm, I think it's just a matter of correctly exporting the model as described e.g. here: https://medium.com/@hamedmp/exporting-trained-tensorflow-models-to-c-the-right-way-cf24b609d183. I'll try it out tomorrow.