# How to benchmark a model in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, benchmarking

I know that there is a simple way to benchmark the forward pass of a caffe model with the `-time` parameter.

Is there an equivalent in the Keras - Framework available, where I can simple specify the Keras-Model architecture and then get time needed for a forward pass?

I sadly could not find anything relatable

Comment: look into this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434292/benchmark-keras-model-using-tensforflow-benchmark

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Not directly, however one should be able to do it with the tensorflow backend. TF provides a benchmark tool - however this is a workaround and not a direct solution

Comment: @Kev1n91 I got it to work using the benchmark tool. See the linked question.