# Freezing Keras K.function() as tensorflow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I have a model trained in Keras, and I'm using its intermediate layer output by using `K.function()`. Is there a way to save this `K.function()` object as a tensorflow graph? I'd like to use this object in tensorflow serving but I don't see a way to freeze Keras `K.function()` objects

Comment: not sure if I understand it correctly, but if what you want is to freeze the layers you can use the trainable attribute for each layer, as described [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4471) and [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/)

Comment: that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking to freeze it into a tensorflow graph so I can use it with tensorflow serving. Not a keras model or layer

Comment: Have at look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434292/benchmark-keras-model-using-tensforflow-benchmark

Comment: Thanks @marcopah. I modified the code a bit to work for a K.function object instead of an entire keras model. See below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out eventually, figured I should post it here in case anyone needs this in the future. I had to get the node names from the `K.function()` object.

```
encoder = K.function([...])  # define your Function object
encoder_tensor_names = [t.name for t in encoder.outputs]
encoder_node_names = [tn.replace(':0', '') for tn in encoder_tensor_names]  # node names are tensor names without :0
graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
    K.get_session(), 
    K.get_session().graph.as_graph_def(), 
    encoder_node_names 
)
```

Then follow the code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44044405/5453184 to write out the binary (or text) file. The beauty of it is that tensorflow is smart enough to only retain the part of the graph that's required for the feedforward operation, and in my case it also freezes word embeddings so I no longer need separate word vector files.